# Dynamically create html content for each new object of a given class

Tags: jquery, html, css, less

As I am a newbie in Web development, I am not sure which tool - CSS, or JavaScript can implement this.

My goal is the following. I want an element of certain class to have a certain content. For example, I want all my "td" elements to have a content like `<input class = "tableRowChecker" type="checkbox">` if they are of class `target_class`. 
Currently I achieve this by creating a hidden 'model' of the content, make it invisible and then after the document is loaded, I find all `td.target_class` elements and populate their html attribute by the hidden building block's content:

HTML:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.target_class').html($('#building_block').html());
    $('button').on('click', function() {build_my_clone()});
});

function build_my_clone() {
  alert("Don't know what to do here");
   // I don't like using clone, because it copies the object with the text values and
   // removing them and adding the new ones makes the element glimmer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = 'building_block' hidden><input class = "tableRowChecker" type="checkbox">
</div>

<button>Add new row</button>
<table class="my_table">
    <thead>
       <th style = 'width:1.5em'></th>
       <th></th>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td class = 'target_class'></td><td>A</td></tr>
      <tr><td class = 'target_class'></td><td>B</td></tr>
      <tr><td class = 'target_class'></td><td>C</td></tr>
    </tbody>
```

My question is, what to do if the element of type target_class is created dynamically. I do not want to repeat `$('#target_class_dynamically_created_instance').html($('#building_block').html());` on every occasion in my code. I've got a terrible filling that this is junk code and there's more straightforward way to do this. Is it possible to achieve via CSS or LESS somehow ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Maybe you should give more concrete example

Comment: Check out: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo for us to experiment with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM Listeners for these kind of operaiotns..
eg.,

```
$('#mutable').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
  alert('class changed');
  //your code will go here
 });
```

I am not sure. But check with these kinds of event listeners to write your code inside. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when you dynamically create the elements they can already contain the appropriate classnames and values. Then CSS will provide the styling based on the rules provided to the class, id, etc. The code below shows an example on how to do it for the example you provided.

### HTML

```
<tbody id="table-body">
  <tr>
    <td class='target_class'></td>
    <td class='letter'>
      <input class="tableRowChecker" type="checkbox"> A</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class='target_class'></td>
    <td class='letter'>
      <input class="tableRowChecker" type="checkbox"> B</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

### JS/jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $('.target_class').html($('#building_block').html());
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    build_my_clone();
  });
});

function build_my_clone() {
  var letter = nextLetter($(".letter").last().text());
  $('#table-body').append("<tr><td class='target_class'></td><td class='letter'><input class='tableRowChecker' type='checkbox'>"+letter+"</td></tr>");
}

function nextLetter(s) {
  return s.replace(/([a-zA-Z])[^a-zA-Z]*$/, function(a) {
    var c = a.charCodeAt(0);
    switch (c) {
      case 90:
        return 'A';
      case 122:
        return 'a';
      default:
        return String.fromCharCode(++c);
    }
  });
```

}

### CSS

```
.target_class {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RodCardenas/uqdez1f2/

Comment: Rod, very interesting piece of code. Haven't ever seen trigger method ))
 But I can't see how can I avoid repetitiveness. I still have to call this $(document).trigger('add'); everytime. I need something like "dynamic binding" which say "ADD this content to EACH class of this type - both ones that exist now in DOM and all others that will be created in the future'

Comment: Then when the elements are generated dynamically, you can create them with the class defined and let CSS take care of how the element looks. Let me look at your code and I'll show you what I mean.

Comment: The fiddle below shows how to do it for your example. The code dynamically inserts row that already have the appropriate classes and values in them. CSS then ultimately adds the styling to based on the class name. https://jsfiddle.net/RodCardenas/uqdez1f2/